# better in performance writing general query log: In file or Mysql Table

Tags: mysql

I have one question. Working on mysql database having large amount of data.

Looking to set up general query log. But one thing I was wondering which type of general query log setup will effect less the performance ?

Writing general query log in separate file or getting log in mysql table (mysql.general_log)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: database is pretty much ALWAYS going to have higher overhead than a flat file. but databases are easier to use if you're got multiple things writing at the same time - the whole concurrency management business is already built-in to the db, whereas you have to provide that yourself when dealing with flat files.

Comment: @MarcB, So marc which option would be better to use ?

Comment: how should I know? You've explained nothing of your operational needs. they both have advantages/disadvantages, and saying X instead of Y boils down to opinion, which is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB, I want to analyse what and how many select/insert statements are being fired on tables in DB.

Answer (score 0):

In my quest for a similar answer I came across this post that I feel explains the options and their impact pretty clearly.
http://www.fromdual.com/general_query_log_vs_mysql_performance

According to the post, having the General log disabled is your best performing option.  Logical, right?

The next best option would be writing to a file (non-csv), and writing to a database table will come trailing in after that.